# Can I call another react app in the virtual DOM of a react application?

Tags: reactjs, micro-frontend

I am trying to build a front end by combining two independent React applications.

The caller is the react application(CallerApp) with id=root as usual and configures the following DOM:

```
# index.html
<script type="module" crossorigin="" src="/assets/javascript/my-callee.js"></script>
...
<div id="root"></div>
```

On the other hand, the one being called(CalleeApp) is built in a js file(my-callee.js) with id="callee":

```
# callee.html
...
<div id="callee"></div>
```

Then, I want to use the calling component within the component at the caller, i.e.

```
# CallerApp.tsx

return (
  <div>
    <p>callee app</p>
    <div id="callee"></div> // Is it impossible to call this way?
  </div>
)
```

However, the above code will not be reflected in the DOM. Why is this? If we are doing it wrong, what are the possible ways to accomplish the implementation of the title?

Comment: if you are talking about application no you cannot do that directly, you have to package the app , publish it somewhere ad than use `npm install package-name` in your `Caller App` , but if you are talking about components in a single application you sure can use the `export` in callee and `import` on caller .

Comment: Thanks bro. My intention was to incorporate the  two react applications.

However I don't know why the following differences occur.

# index.html

 cannot display
```<div id="root"><div id="callee"></div></div>```
but display
```<div id="callee"></div>```